# Why when a series converges to L, then its harmonic mean converges to L?

Tags: calculus

I have a proof that $$\text{for } a_n \gt 0 ,a_n \to L \quad \text{then} \cfrac{n}{\cfrac{1}{a_1} +  ... + \cfrac{1}{a_n}}\to L$$
Or, verbally: If a series converges to a limit L, then also its harmonic mean converges to the limit L.

The proof goes as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Phase 1: We know that } \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n} \to L \\
\text{Phase 2: Define} \quad b_n=\frac{1}{a_n} \\
\text{Phase 3: Therefore} \quad b_n \to \frac{1}{L} \\
\text{Phase 4: Inferring that} \quad \frac{b_1+...+b_n}{n} \to \frac{1}{L} \\
\text{Phase 5: Which is equivalent to} \quad \frac{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}{n} \to \frac{1}{L} \implies \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}} \to L\\
\end{array}
$$

I don't understand the following:

1. Why the assumptions in *phases #1 and #3* are allowed?
   (According to which calculus-statements?)
2. Why is it allowed to invert the fractions in *phase #5* ?

Comment: I guess you assume $L>0$?

Comment: Phase one can be proved. It is not an assumption. 2 and 3 (and 5) states that if $a_n \to L$ and $L \neq 0$, then $1/a_n \to 1/L$. That can also be proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 can be proven, for example using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) for $b_n=n$.

3 and 5 comes from following lemma:

If $x_n \to x$ and $x \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{x_n} \to \frac{1}{x}$.

Proof:

If $x_n \to x \neq 0$, then for large $n$ we have $|x_n|>\frac{|x|}{2}$ (because $|x-x_n| + |x_n| \geq |x|$ and $|x-x_n| \to 0$). So note that:

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x_n-x}{x_nx}\right|\leq \left|\frac{2(x-x_n)}{x^2}\right|=\frac{2}{x^2}|x-x_n|$$

But you know that $|x-x_n| \to 0$, $\frac{2}{x^2}$ is constant, so $\frac{2}{x^2}|x-x_n| \to 0$.